# Merge overlapping intervals with respecting type priority

Tags: java, algorithm, intervals

Let's say we have the following enum:

```
// lower value takes precedence
enum Type{ 
  X(1), 
  Y(2), 
  Z(3); 
  ...
}
```

and record:

```
record Interval(Type type, Instant startTime, Instant endTime){}
```

---

And with respect of that `Type` priorities consider the following example of overlapping intervals:

```
     _____________
   1|   ZZZZZZZ
   2|YYYYYY
   3|    XXXXXXXXX
```

---

Let's break this into step by step iteration.

1. Sort the intervals list by `startTime` with ASC order:

```
     _____________
   1|YYYYYY
   2|   ZZZZZZZ
   3|    XXXXXXXXX
```

2. First iteration so just add current interval to list:

```
     ______
   1|YYYYYY
--->|YYYYYY  (content of new merged intervals list)
```

3. Add new interval to list but shrink it beacuse last Y interval have priority:

```
     __________
   1|YYYYYY
   2|   ZZZZZZZ
--->|YYYYYYZZZZ  (content of new merged intervals list)
```

4. X interval comes in 3rd iteration with priority over the last two. Remove last interval and also shrink one before last:

```
     _____________
   1|YYYYYY
   2|   ZZZZZZZ
   3|    XXXXXXXXX
--->|YYYYXXXXXXXXX  (content of new merged intervals list)
```

As you can see I am trying to merge those intervals but those `type` makes everything much harder because in some cases (3rd iteration for example) I have to search back my list. The problem is not only previous element but even further. That is only one example, the things could be much more complicated. I am afraid that case where I will have to go back and replace / shrink / delete several intervals elements from stack would be possible. Could someone give me a hint how to handle this problem with grace? I am afraid my idea of solving this problem is bad...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every time event make a tuple containing `(time; type; boolean field for interval start/interval end)`, create array/list `L` of these tuples, sort them by time field.

Make auxiliary list `A` for storing active intervals in sorted (by type) order.

Walk through the list `L`.

When you meet interval start, check if type is lower then `A[0]`. If yes, begin interval for output, insert type in front of `A`. If no, find position for type in `A` using binary search and insert type into corresponding position.

When you meet interval end, check if current type is A[0]. If yes, terminate interval for output, begin new interval for output using `A[1]` (if exists). Find and remove type from `A` list.

---

If you have very large list, updating list `A` becomes time-consuming operation, and you'll need some special data structure instead of list (like priority queue with dictionary for searching)

Comment: After some days and several improvements of corner cases I managed to successfully implement algorithm that follows your idea. Thank you very much!